# Unit test success individually, but after running all tests some fails

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database, ef-core-3.1

I'm using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory/3.1.16.
my tests pass when I run them individually but when I run all tests some of them fail.

**Sdk :.net core 3.1**

here is my optionbuilder configuration:

```
public static DbContextOptionsBuilder<T> GetDbContextOptionsBuilder<T>( string? connectionString =null , Guid? databaseId = null)
      where T : DbContext
    {
      var optionBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<T>();
      if (databaseId is null)
        databaseId = Guid.NewGuid();

      optionBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase( $"dbApi-{databaseId:N}",
                                        x => {
                                          x.UseHierarchyId();
                                        } )
                   .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                   .EnableDetailedErrors();
      return optionBuilder;
    }
public static DbContextOptionsBuilder<T> GetInDbContextOptionsBuilder<T>( IConfiguration configuration )
      where T : DbContext
    {
      configuration ??= ConfigHelper.GetConfig();
      return GetDbContextOptionsBuilder<T>( configuration.GetConnectionString( "DefaultConnection" ) );
    }
```

and how my unit tests call dbContext like this:

```
await using var db = new WriteContext(DbContextInitialization.GetDbContextOptionsBuilder<WriteContext>().Options);
```

in tests I seed some data like this:

```
db.SeedTemplate(); //test 1
db.SeedCategory(); //test 2
```

when I run the tests it throws following error:
The instance of entity type 'entity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

**Edit 1:**
I add two sample tests:

```
//This test will pass
[Fact]
    public async Task Can_Add_Template_With_Attribute()
    {
      await using var db = new WriteContext(DbContextInitialization.GetDbContextOptionsBuilder<WriteContext>().Options);
//priceAttribute and displayAttribute removed for brevity
      template.LinkAttributes( new List<Attribute>{ priceAttribute,displayAttribute} );
      await db.Templates.AddAsync( template);
      await db.SaveChangesAsync();
      
      var actualTemplate = await db.Templates.FirstAsync();
      actualTemplate.ShouldNotBeNull();
      actualTemplate.Attributes.First().ShouldEqual( priceAttribute ););
    }


//This test will throw error
[Fact]
    public async Task Can_Delete_Template()
    {
      await using var db         = new WriteContext(DbContextInitialization.GetDbContextOptionsBuilder<WriteContext>().Options, MediatorHelper.Initialize());
     //priceAttribute and displayAttribute removed for brevity
      template.LinkAttributes( new List<Attribute>{ priceAttribute,displayAttribute} );
      await db.Templates.AddAsync( template);
      await db.SaveChangesAsync();

      template.Delete();
      var command = new DeleteTemplateCommand( template.Id );
      var handler = new DeleteTemplateCommand.DeleteTemplateCommandHandler( db );
      var result=await handler.Handle( command,CancellationToken.None );
      result.Should().BeSuccess();
      
      var actualTemplate = await db.Templates.FirstAsync();
      actualTemplate.IsDeleted.ShouldBeTrue();
      
    }
```

Comment: EF themselves don't recommend using in memory for tests.

Comment: Probably because `UseHierarchyId` is not In-memory provider extension method. And there can be big differences in queries execution.

Comment: Any chance you have the [`Parallelize` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.parallelizeattribute) on your test assembly or a `/RunSettings/MSTest/Parallelize` configuration in its .runsettings file?

Comment: No I don' have ParallelizeAttribute class.